# Loop asking too many inputs at once

Tags: java, loops

Recently I have been studying Java and I came across a small problem with a loop, what i would like the program to do is, for example if the user enters 2 for number of passengers, that the program would ask for the names of both, save them and print the names.

One of the main issues is that the program asks for both passengers details at the same time - it looks like this:

```
Please enter the number of passengers:
2
Please enter passenger 1 details:
Please enter passenger 2 details:
```

Also it only takes one name and prints it at the end butu should show list of all passengers on that ticket:

```
    count=1;
    do{
        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter passenger " + count +" details:");
            passengerName=keyboard.nextLine();
            count++;

        }while (count<=numOfPassengers);
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }while (count<=numOfPassengers);

    passengerInfo +="\nPassenger "+count+": "+passengerName;
    keyboard.nextLine();

    //ticket printout section
    System.out.println("Ticket");
    System.out.println("======");
    System.out.println("Number of Passengers: "+numOfPassengers);
    System.out.println(passengerInfo);
   }       
}
```

Comment: Why are you using double `do/while` loops?

Comment: Please make your title relevant to problem you are facing. This will let others with same problem find your question (and possibly answers) easier.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You'll need to consider a different datastructure (List? Array?) and check those loops I guess.

Comment: your'e not saving the individual names anyways. you just prompt for a name, stuff it into `passenger`, the move right on to asking for the next name, overwriting the previous name.

Comment: Ugh reading that logic makes my head hurt

Comment: sorry i forgot to take out the extra do-while but problem still persists

Answer (score 2):

Consider these changes - based on the fact that for now you seem to be satisfied with a `String` holding all passenger information:

```
    String passengerInfo = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPassengers; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Please enter passenger " + (i+1) +" details:");
        passengerInfo +="\nPassenger "+(i+1)+": "+keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    //ticket printout section
    System.out.println("Ticket");
    System.out.println("======");
    System.out.println("Number of Passengers: "+numOfPassengers);
    System.out.println(passengerInfo);
```

As a next step you might want to think about collection the passengers into a List:

```
    List<String> passengers = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPassengers; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Please enter passenger " + (i+1) +" details:");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        passengerInfo +="\nPassenger "+(i+1)+": "+name;
        passengers.add(name);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what twit marked you down - but both answers sound entirely reasonable :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    count=1;
    do{

            System.out.println("Please enter passenger " + count +" details:");
            passengerName=keyboard.nextLine();
            count++;
        keyboard.nextLine();    
    passengerInfo +="\nPassenger "+count+": "+passengerName;

    //ticket printout section
    System.out.println("Ticket");
    System.out.println("======");
    System.out.println("Number of Passengers: "+numOfPassengers);
    System.out.println(passengerInfo);
   }while (count<=numOfPassengers);
   }       
}
```

Comment: check the additional nextLine() below passengerInfo += - that seems of very little value?! And your answer could benefit from improved indentation I guess

Comment: Ah sorry, ill edit the next line thingy. thanks for pointing it out.